# What happens if i use not enough memory in placement form of new in c++?

Tags: c++

I studied about placement form of new, But i did not get clear idea. They says The placement form of new allows you create a object from already allocated memory. But see the following code.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class ex
{
 public:
  int x;
  int y;
  double z;
    ex()
    {
     cout<<"constructor";
    }
    ~ex()
    {
        cout<<"destructor";
    }
};

int main()
{
   char *pt=new char;

   ex *p;
   p=new(pt) ex();
   p->x=4444;
   p->y=3333;
   p->z=65.87879898;
   cout<<"\n"<<p->x<<"\n"<<p->y<<"\n"<<p->z<<"\n";
   p->~ex();

   free(pt);
   return 0;
}
```

I expected above code fails to run, but it run successfully produces the following output:

```
 constructor
 4444
 3333
 65.8788
 destructor
 Process returned 0 (0x0)   execution time : 0.106 s
 Press any key to continue.
```

How this code runs?

I did not get clear idea about placement form of new so any of please explain that concept and syntax with a sample code.Any one please.

Thank you.

Comment: `I expected above code fails to run` - why would you expect that? How do you expect the code to fail?

Comment: Because the previous allocated memory is equal to char but, it used in placement form of new, How the memory allocated to class ex.

Comment: Compile your code with `-fsanitize=address` and it will point out that you're using unallocated memory.

Comment: Since `pt` points to less than `sizeof(ex)` bytes of memory, the behavior is undefined, and the program can do anything. Including not crashing.

Comment: if the line is char *pt=new char; to char *pt=new char[sizeof(ex)]; it is correct.

Comment: Yes, it should work.

Comment: if char is grater than 1 byte or if  char *pt=new char[sizeof(ex)]; changed to int *pt=new int[sizeof(ex)]; it is wrong.

Comment: *How this code runs?* More often than not, C++ only defines what will happen when your program is correct. If it is not correct, what happens is left up to the compiler. As a result code that does not work might do anything from look like it works to everything else it could do. Not providing enough storage usually falls into this category because it is very hard to detect in the general case and expensive to detect at runtime. The usual term for this is [Undefined Behaviour.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior)

Comment: @Srilakshmikanthanp Providing more memory than needed is not an error.

Comment: void *pt=malloc(sizeof(ex));
   ex *p;
   p=new(pt) ex(); I changed to like this , I Think it is not wrong, But the compiler gives warning deleting 'void*' is undefined [-Wdelete-incomplete] How do i overcome that or it is wrong Thanks For helping

Comment: If you `malloc`, you must `free`, not `delete`

Comment: Thanks all of you for helping me.

Comment: "I Think it is not wrong, But the compiler gives warning" - The compiler gives you a warning for a *reason*. 99% sure it is wrong and the compiler is correct to warn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code is using unallocated memory.

This does not mean it **has** to crash, it's more in the field of "unexpected result".

This code **can** and probably will crash, if run for a long time, as soon as your memory corruption will override something important / access memory outside of the process's allocated page limits.